# C "block" caret character

Tags: c, declaration, caret

I've noticed that [this declaration involving a caret (^) character](https://cdecl.org/?q=cast+foo+into+block%28int%2C+long+long%29+returning+double) is pinned on the cdecl.org site at the top:

```
// "cast foo into block(int, long long) returning double"
(double (^)(int , long long ))foo
```

Can somebody explain what is the purpose of the caret character here? Is this really a valid character in C declarations, or is this a placeholder for something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The caret is part of an extension to the C language to work with [blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29). Blocks are an extension to C supported by Clang and Apple’s GCC. It is not strictly conforming C (that is, not part of the core C language defined by the C standard).

Answer (score 3):

It is known as [`Block Variable Declaration`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html#block-variable-declarations). A variable with [Block type](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html#the-block-type) is declared using function pointer style notation substituting `^` for `*`.